# How to call an exports function of a controller in the same controller?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 functions,

```
exports.first = function () {
     second('hai');
}

exports.second = function (type) {
      console.log(type);
}
```

But when I call the first function from another controller, it says second is not a function. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the function to `export object` and not to `this`.

So,you should call it using `export` object.

```
exports.first = function () {
         exports.second('hai');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this?

```
exports.first = function () {
     exports.second('hai');
}

exports.second = function (type) {
      console.log(type);
}
```

This should work. Let me know if not.